# What is the difference in the usage of punctuation with "For instance","For example","Such as" on the SAT?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Especially on the SAT writing section this kind of questions frequently happen, so I was wondering if anyone could give me a clear explanation on the English punctuation usage with this words during different scenarios like "When they come at the beginning of a sentence if they do", "at the end of an independent clause", "In the middle of a sentence" and so on ..

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Mentioning in the title is not enough. Include the question in the body as well. Good Luck.

Comment: See also: [ell.se]